# Limit certain user groups to only see their own documents?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, workflow, infopath

I've been more or less going along with the rough steps provided in [this](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2011/07/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-help-desk/) guide to make a support forum.

However, I have a concern that the end-user will not be able to send any further updates on the situation (knowing that support often has a large amount of back and forth).

What I would really like to do is to be able to have the users that aren't in a specific group of support desk workers only be able to see their own tickets. Any thoughts on the best way to achieve this?

(The other option that I considered is to create a separate list like they suggested, and then have a field that can be populated that will say whether or not to update the end user with the most recent comments, but that comes back to the issue where they can't provide any further clarification.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said "documents" in the title, but the link you referenced shows how to set up a couple of lists. In SharePoint, that vocabulary is pretty important, as there are some significant functionality differences between them, as well as some obscure differences. One obscure difference is that lists have an option that enables people to only see their own items. Libraries lack this option. So, if you are dealing with a list, and not a library, navigate to list settings --> advanced settings, and see the section titled "Item-level Permissions".

Comment: Thank you! I actually had a chance to talk to a Sharepoint expert this morning, and that's the suggestion he gave as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the view to do this.  In the filter section, do a filter where AssignedTo = [Me].  This will force the view to only show items from the current logged in user.

Comment: The issue with this approach was that there were going to be end users (not support desk members) that were able to see all open tickets if they went to another view, which is never a good thing for a support organization.

Comment: Put audience targeting on your views and make you default view one that can be viewed by all.